# Object is added to a list, but not sorted with other objects, but added at the end

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

I added object to the list, but when I sort list, everything is nicely sorted; only new object is added at the end. Any ideas?

This is code:

```
// creating object
ScheduleDay sDay = new ScheduleDay();
// all attributes are optional; but even if I add them all, it still isn't sorted
sDay.setDate(dt1.format(cal.getTime()));
// adding to the list
standardShiftItemsPerEmployee.add(sDay);

// sorting
Arrays.sort(standardShiftItemsPerEmployee.toArray());

for (ScheduleDay s : standardShiftItemsPerEmployee)
        System.out.println(s.getDate());
```

Result:

08-09-2014

09-09-2014

10-09-2014

11-09-2014

12-09-2014

**06-09-2014**

Comment: That is what a `List` is supposed to do.  Are you asking how to use a sorted collection, how to sort the collection or just checking if your understanding of List is correct?

Comment: BTW The array you are sorting, you are discarding. i.e. you don't use the array again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `Arrays.sort(standardShiftItemsPerEmployee.toArray());` by `Collections.sort(standardShiftItemsPerEmployee)`

Comment: How does this fix his problem?

Comment: @mostruash current code sort array returned by toArray() which is not underlying array but copy of it

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.sort(standardShiftItemsPerEmployee.toArray());`

This doesn't sort your collection. It creates a new array containing the elements of the collection, and sorts that array. And you are not keeping any reference to that sorted array.

The order of the elements in the collection remains unchanged.